# How can I view what an indexed and analyzer string looks like?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I view the value of a string attribute which went though an analyzer?

Comment: Use the termvectors API or just a terms aggregation which ever matches your needs

Comment: @sramalingam24 could you provide an example maybe?

Comment: Here you go https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Comment: Also here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: You can view how a given analyzer configured for a field will analyze a piece of text using the Analyze API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/testing-analyzers.html#_testing_an_analyzer_on_a_field